# How to find out which path is running a process when it is shown in blank / empty in the command line of the task Manager

Tags: powershell

How do I find out in Powershell which path is running a process when it is shown in blank / empty in the command line of the Task Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are processes (e. g. "csrss.exe") that run in a higher security context (see [protected processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights#protected-processes)) than the current PowerShell session, even if the PowerShell session runs as administrator. For such processes, PowerShell isn't able to query some informations like the process path using `Get-Process` or the .NET `Process` class, because PowerShell doesn't have the required permissions.

It depends on the kind of API being used though. Since Windows Vista there is a newer *native* API [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamew) that works when the process is opened using the flag [`PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-security-and-access-rights). AFAIK this functionality isn't available as a .NET API, so you have to use P/Invoke:

```sh
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

public static class WinApiProcess {
    [Flags]
    public enum ProcessAccess
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to create a thread.
        /// </summary>
        CreateThread = 0x0002,
    
        /// <summary>
        ///
        /// </summary>
        SetSessionId = 0x0004,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to perform an operation on the address space of a process
        /// </summary>
        VmOperation = 0x0008,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to read memory in a process using ReadProcessMemory.
        /// </summary>
        VmRead = 0x0010,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to write to memory in a process using WriteProcessMemory.
        /// </summary>
        VmWrite = 0x0020,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to duplicate a handle using DuplicateHandle.
        /// </summary>
        DupHandle = 0x0040,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to create a process.
        /// </summary>
        CreateProcess = 0x0080,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to set memory limits using SetProcessWorkingSetSize.
        /// </summary>
        SetQuota = 0x0100,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to set certain information about a process, such as its priority class (see SetPriorityClass).
        /// </summary>
        SetInformation = 0x0200,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to retrieve certain information about a process, such as its token, exit code, and priority class (see OpenProcessToken).
        /// </summary>
        QueryInformation = 0x0400,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to suspend or resume a process.
        /// </summary>
        SuspendResume = 0x0800,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to retrieve certain information about a process (see GetExitCodeProcess, GetPriorityClass, IsProcessInJob, QueryFullProcessImageName).
        /// A handle that has the PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION access right is automatically granted PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION.
        /// </summary>
        QueryLimitedInformation = 0x1000,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to wait for the process to terminate using the wait functions.
        /// </summary>
        Synchronize = 0x100000,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to delete the object.
        /// </summary>
        Delete = 0x00010000,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to read information in the security descriptor for the object, not including the information in the SACL.
        /// To read or write the SACL, you must request the ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY access right. For more information, see SACL Access Right.
        /// </summary>
        ReadControl = 0x00020000,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to modify the DACL in the security descriptor for the object.
        /// </summary>
        WriteDac = 0x00040000,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Required to change the owner in the security descriptor for the object.
        /// </summary>
        WriteOwner = 0x00080000,
    
        StandardRightsRequired = 0x000F0000,
    
        /// <summary>
        /// All possible access rights for a process object.
        /// </summary>
        AllAccess = StandardRightsRequired | Synchronize | 0xFFFF
    }
    
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hprocess, int dwFlags,
                StringBuilder lpExeName, out int size);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccess dwDesiredAccess,
                bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hHandle); 

    public static string QueryProcessPath(int ProcessId)
    {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder(1024);
        IntPtr hprocess = OpenProcess(ProcessAccess.QueryLimitedInformation, false, ProcessId);
        if (hprocess != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            try
            {
                int size = buffer.Capacity;
                if (QueryFullProcessImageName(hprocess, 0, buffer, out size))
                {
                    return buffer.ToString();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseHandle(hprocess);
            }
        }
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }
}
'@
```

Usage example:

```sh
[WinApiProcess]::QueryProcessPath( (Get-Process csrss)[0].Id )
```

This works for me when PowerShell runs *elevated* ("as administrator").

Answer (score 0):

Finally works , the problem was that to show all the info, I needed to use a user with elevated privileges or DC admin.   Then you can see the full info

Many thanks for your help