# Get full executable path of SYSTEM process without full admin rights/elevation on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, openprocess

On Windows, it is possible to enumerate all running processes on the system, e.g. via the [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) API.

However, this will directly only report the executable *name* and the process ID without further info.

To identify the binary of the process, you need to `OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION...)` and [`QueryFullProcessImageName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamew).

And OpenProcess, even with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, requires the `SeDebugPrivilege` when you need to query processes run under an elevated context - which means you need to be admin / elevated.

**Question**: Is it possible to get the full path to the binary of ANY given process (ID), *including Windows services running as SYSTEM and other admin processes*, without the `SeDebugPrivilege` or even better without requiring any additional rights from a non-elevated context?

OS: Windows 10 from v1809 upwards.

Here is the C++ example code to read out the info: https://gist.github.com/bilbothebaggins/f5852dbf22177620975207fe60f2f1f1

On my machine, given that I run with UAC, non-elevated, I see:

- I can query my own processes (non-elevated)
- I can also query a process started by another local, non-privileged user.
- Query on all Windows services fails. (These running as SYSTEM)

---

X Y problem disclaimer: As a pre-build step, I need to determine for a given local directory if any (different user / admin / Windows service) background processes are running who's executables/binaries reside in the local directory. The build runs as non-admin. I can think of various other workarounds for this (all more complicated in our case), so can we stick to the question as asked above for this here? Thanks.

Comment: From a non-elevated PowerShell process I can get paths of non-elevated processes using `QueryFullProcessImageName`, without `SeDebugPrivilege`. See [PowerShell example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74030307/7571258).

Comment: Are you looking for *system* processes? I believe you should be able to get the full path to non-system processes using only `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` with `QueryFullProcessImageName`, but not for system processes; for those, you'll need `SeDebugPrivilege`. I assume you have code that you have written implementing this to test it out? Can you share that? Would probably make it easier for others to debug.

Comment: @CodyGray - I have now added a link to the code gist. While doing this I noticed that I messed up while writing the question, because "of course" :-) I need to (also) access SYSTEM processes.

Comment: @zett42 - yeah, I failed to clearly mention that I also want to read SYSTEM processes. My bad. Added code and fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using `NtQuerySystemInformation` with `SystemProcessIdInformation` *(0x58)* - with this way - we not need open process handle.

```
typedef struct SYSTEM_PROCESS_ID_INFORMATION
{
    HANDLE ProcessId;
    UNICODE_STRING ImageName;
} *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_ID_INFORMATION;

NTSTATUS GetProcessPathById(HANDLE ProcessId)
{
    SYSTEM_PROCESS_ID_INFORMATION spii = { ProcessId, { 0, 0x80 } };
    NTSTATUS status;

    do 
    {
        if (spii.ImageName.Buffer)
        {
            LocalFree(spii.ImageName.Buffer);
        }

        if (!(spii.ImageName.Buffer = (PWSTR)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, spii.ImageName.MaximumLength)))
        {
            status = STATUS_NO_MEMORY;
            break;
        }

    } while (STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH == (status = 
        NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessIdInformation, &spii, sizeof(spii), 0)));

    if (0 > status)
    {
        DbgPrint("%p - %x\n", ProcessId, status); 
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("%p - %wZ\n", ProcessId, &spii.ImageName);
    }

    if (spii.ImageName.Buffer)
    {
        LocalFree(spii.ImageName.Buffer);
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: The `NtQuerySystemInformation` function is documented as one that application developers should not use, and the `SystemProcessIdInformation` information class is *not even documented*. This is not a reasonable solution to the problem.

Comment: @CodyGray - i have another opinion.

Comment: If a solution is based off of unsupported functionality, that should be **explicitly** called out in an answer. It is crucial information for engineers that need to answer questions as mundane as: *"What OS versions do we need to test?"* or *"Will this run on a yet-to-be-released version of Windows?"*.

Comment: @IInspectable this is on all versions begin from vista

Comment: That is understood. But how does that help answer the second question: *"Will this run on a yet-to-be-released version of Windows?"*.

Comment: @IInspectable you know this answer

Comment: I will acknowledge your confidence in me, but no, I don't know the answer. I'm not clairvoyant. Unless *"maybe"* counts as an answer.

Comment: @IInspectable how many native api removed or changed ? How many infoclass for system info removed or changed? I dont know any changed for 20+ years. But maybe you know. Api related to event pair and ldt is gone ( more exactly return now error ) but probably you know much more and can enum